# Difficulty using the function

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I want to add a unit to the length and width of the table with each click on "btn1". This is the code:

```
from tkinter import*
win=Tk()
y=3
def func():
    global y
    y+=1
func()
for i in range(1,y):
    for j in range(1,y):
        frm=Frame(win,bd=2)
        frm.grid(row=i,column=j)
        btn=Button(frm,bg="red")
        btn.grid()
btn1=Button(win,command=func)
btn1.grid()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: and what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: The callback is changing y when it is too late. Your for loops that set your grid already ran and they are done by the time one can press the button. You will need an approach that recreates or adds to the grid in the callback function.

Comment: With each click, the 3 * 3 table remains.

Comment: Of course it remains, because your callback is only altering y after it was used in making the table. Your callback is not altering the table.

Answer (score 0):

Create a seperate function where the frames are being added.

This way, everytime the button is clicked new frames are added to the window. We also call the function one time before defining `btn1` so that we have a button to click in the first place.

```
from tkinter import*
win=Tk()
y=3

def addFrames():
    for i in range(1,y):
        for j in range(1,y):
            frm=Frame(win,bd=2)
            frm.grid(row=i,column=j)
            btn=Button(frm,bg="red")
            btn.grid()
def func():
    global y
    y+=1
    addFrames()

addFrames()
btn1=Button(win,command=func)
btn1.grid()
win.mainloop()
```